# Selected language not applied on "cold" site

Tags: sharepoint-server

We have installed the Dutch language pack on our SharePoint 2013 server and create every site collection with Dutch as the default language.

We experience the following behavior when we visit a root site which is no longer cached:

1. Text is shown in English
2. User name (top right) shown claim encoded (0#.w|...)

On refreshing the page, everything works as expected.

Does anyone have any idea what causes this problem (and how to solve it)?